# Avoid close modal dialog bootstrap and jsf

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2

Well, i have a modal dialog in bootstrap that works with `<h:commandButton>`. I'm trying to avoid close dialog when validation failed but didn't work.

This is my button to call modal:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default"
                 type="button"
                 value="Criar Página"
                 actionListener="#{cursoMB.novaPaginaConteudo()}">

    <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-toggle" value="modal" />

    <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-target"
                            value="#modalDialogPagina" />

    <f:ajax execute="@this"
            render="modalPagina"
            onevent="function(data) {if(data.status==='success') initSummerNote(); }"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

And this is my button on modal:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default"
                 actionListener="#{cursoMB.salvarPagina()}" 
                 value="Salvar">

    <f:ajax execute="modalPagina"
            render="tabPaginas"
            onevent="function(data){if(data.status!='success') data.preventDefault();}"/>

    <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-dismiss" value="modal" />
</h:commandButton>
```

If `data.status != 'sucess'`, I would like avoiding close but nothing happens. How can I do it?

Comment: Is `data.preventDefault()` what you want?  I'm thinking there's something else you want to `preventDefault()` on, such as the button click.  Or just do nothing in that case (or `alert('cannot close.');`).  You should also use Firebug or a similar tool to inspect the live page to see what JS lurks behind the button once it's rendered.

Comment: I'm not sure if "data.preventDefault()" is the right way to avoid modal close. This didn't work and i'm searching for another way to avoid modal close.

Comment: did you solve problem?? I have same issue right now:/

Answer (score 0):

Create a control variable in bean (like boolean xxx) and set this variable with true in case of error.

In AJAX function test this variable. If false ( !xxx ) hide modal.

example:

```
function nameFunction(data) {
   var status = data.status;
   switch (status) {
      case 'success':
         if (!xxx) {
            $('#idModal').modal('hide');
         }
         break;
   }
}
```